# Fixing Pip Error code for installing any package

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

sorry I am fairly new to all this, but a short background to the problem is when I initially installed python 3.8.5 and pycharm I followed the instructions on a youtube video which saved python to a custom directory.  When I later was downloading other apps for my computing course one of them (nodejs) downloaded another version of python (3.9) as it couldn't find the other version of python on my computer.
I decided to just uninstall the older version and reconfigure pycharm to the new interpreter. BUT ever since I have been unable to use python to install any packages such as matplotlib or scipy.  Every time I attempt to I get the following errors.  I have uninstalled that version of python and tried to install a new version from the python website but I still have the same problem.  Any help would be very appreciated.

I probably should state that I am currently using windows 10.

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2020.06.20 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.2)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib, pillow
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for matplotlib: filename=matplotlib-3.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=8427385 sha256=2281d01056220920876048430b733d3eb9cd2e230beb23f8abddf43f8c192979
  Stored in directory: c:\users\owner\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a6\65\5d\e2634e905fc0a7d4486dfc5acd9e68b48aae52634d82c5ed69
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2boayhms'
       cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\
  Complete output (172 lines):
  C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Successfully built matplotlib
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow, matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z_802pca\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow'
         cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\
    Complete output (174 lines):
    C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xtbfbx_6\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z_802pca\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install matplotlib --no-cache-dir
```

Trying this resulted in the following error---

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 37.9 MB 3.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2020.06.20 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.2)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 39.1 MB 939 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib, pillow
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for matplotlib: filename=matplotlib-3.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=8427385 sha256=d2ec11ec27a85f7a0781b90dde5bd35def7efba5d4a30e9f86f2cd9edb7145fb
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r27tbp3m\wheels\a6\65\5d\e2634e905fc0a7d4486dfc5acd9e68b48aae52634d82c5ed69
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-zd_m2h6g'
       cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\
  Complete output (172 lines):
  C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
      raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
      raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Successfully built matplotlib
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow, matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l2nxey6_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow'
         cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\
    Complete output (174 lines):
    C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1yfgbo11\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1yfgbo11\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l2nxey6_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pillow' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I tried what you said and while it downloaded matplotlib and pillow it still gave the above error after ```` Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html